# Get sublists from list which match predicate

Tags: scala, list, predicate

I'm very new to Scala, but from what I've read it seems the ideal language to tackle the project I'm working on.

I have a very large CSV file which looks like this:

```
INDEX, CITY, COST
  7  ,  London, 500
  7  ,  Paris, 200
  11  ,  Rome, 300
  11  ,  New York, 100
  11  ,  Madrid, 7
```

I want to read in the CSV file and produce a list of all the elements with the same index, one index at a time.

From the above example I would like to get a list containing the rows:

```
7, London, 500
7, Paris, 200
```

And a second list containing the rows:

```
11, Rome, 300
11, New York, 100
11, Madrid, 7
```

It's pretty easy to read in the CSV file:

```
val iter = src.getLines().drop(1).map(_.split(",")) //from SO :)
```

However, I'm struggling to find a clean way of generating my sub-lists. It seems to me that there should be a nice, concise way of achieving this using Scala. I would particularly like the data to be lazy-loaded since there is a lot of it. Could you suggest how I achieve this?

All of the data is in order by index (though the indexes are not sequential), and the CSV file I'm working with does not contain any nested commas or escapes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Source.getLines is already lazy.  It returns an Iterator, which will fech each line from the underlying file on demand.  Most operations on Iterators also return iterators, so in the following code:

```
val iter = src.getLines.tail map {_ split ","}
```

You named the value correctly.  It'll be an `Iterator[Array[String]]`, with each String array being produced on demand.

Have you run into any particular issues that would suggest the data isn't being loaded lazily?

**UPDATE**

To then produce one of your sublists from this Iterator, you can:

```
val id7 = iter filter {_(0) == 7)
```

Again, this will still be lazy.

Or... you can group the lot:

```
val grouped = iter.toStream groupBy {_(0)}
```

Unfortunately, this isn't completely lazy.  The very last row may have a unique value in the first column, so you need to read every element from the input to know how many subdivisions are required.  In the REPL, it's also easier to force the sub-streams, so you can see what they contain:

```
val grouped = iter.toStream groupBy {_(0)} mapValues {_.toList}
```

Comment: Sorry, no I haven't run into a problem, it's just something I do want the code to achieve. What I can't figure out is how to group the rows by index, essentially I want an Array[Array[String]] grouping every row with the same value in the index column.

Answer (score 2):

```
scala> List(Array(1,"a"),Array(2,"b"),Array(1,"c")).groupBy(_(0))
res1: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Any,List[Array[Any]]] = Map(1 -> List(Array(1, a), Array(1, c)), 2 -> List(Array(2, b)))
```

So what you have to do is add `.groupBy(_(0))` to group by the first element inside the arrays.

Comment: +1. Doesn't preserve the order, but then the OP hasn't asked for that.

Comment: The OP *did* however ask for lazy-loading, which this answer completely sidesteps

Answer (score 1):

When you have a lot of data, you have to be more careful about which operations you want to do.

Let's suppose that your file is *so* big that you can't load it all into memory, and in exchange you're willing to (forced to) read it in ~`N` times in order to get the `N` different subsets.

First, you should figure out how many subsets you're going to need.  Let's create something that has a pretend getLines method:

```
val src = new { def getLines() = Iterator("#", "1,a", "2,b", "2,c") }
```

Now we need to find all initial indices.  You *could* use `split`, but since you're processing lots of data and don't really need it all broken down, let's just find the first comma (here assuming that there is always a comma to be found):

```
val idx = Set() ++ src.getLines().drop(1).map(s => s.substring(0, s.indexOf(',')))
```

Okay, now we know what we're looking for.  Then we go through and get it, with the aid of a class that will help us lazy-load the data:

```
class OneIndex(index: String) {
  lazy val data = src.getLines().drop(1).filter(
    s => index == s.substring(0,s.indexOf(','))
  ).toArray
}
val everything = idx.map(i => (i,new OneIndex(i))).toMap

scala> everything("2").data.foreach(println)
2,b
2,c
```

There are many more things one might add in--maybe `.toInt` or `.trim.toInt` would help at some point, to turn index values from strings into ints.  One might also wonder whether you really want lazy-loading since it forces you to read the entire file multiple times.  But this is at least a basic framework.